# Scala Map: Combine keys with the same value?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose I have a `Map` like

```
val x = Map(1 -> List("a", "b"), 2 -> List("a"), 
            3 -> List("a", "b"), 4 -> List("a"), 
            5 -> List("c"))
```

How would I create from this a new `Map` where the keys are `List`s of keys from `x` having the same value, e.g., how can I implement

```
def someFunction(m: Map[Int, List[String]]): Map[List[Int], List[String]] = 
  // stuff that would turn x into
  // Map(List(1, 3) -> List("a", "b"), List(2, 4) -> List("a"), List(5) -> List("c"))
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the Map to a List and then use `groupBy` to aggregate the first element of each tuple:

```
x.toList.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1)).map{ case (x, y) => (y, x) }

// res37: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[Int],List[String]] = 
//        Map(List(2, 4) -> List(a), List(1, 3) -> List(a, b), List(5) -> List(c))
```

---

Or as @Dylan commented, use `_.swap` to switch the tuples' elements:

```
x.toList.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1)).map(_.swap)
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds with pretty much the exact same solution, so I'll give you the +1 and add that you can use `_.swap` in the final `map` call.

Comment: @Dylan Ah, didn't know the `_.swap` method before. Thank you!